# .csproj bug in Asp .NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have wanted to create new table in my database (SQLite), so I created new Model and used it in ApplicationDbContext class like this:

```
   public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
```

Then executed the command later:
**dotnet ef migrations add Report**
I can see migration file. 
In Startup.cs file I have:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
 services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

In EFRepository.cs:

```
 public IQueryable<AppUser> AppUsers
            => ctx.AppUsers;
        public IQueryable<Report> Reports => ctx.Reports;
```

After this somehow suddenly I received many errors connected with this file ( **.csproj**):

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Mushrooms</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Mushrooms</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I checked dotnet --info command, but I can't see incompatibility.
Three of the errors:

> Invalid markup declaration '<'
>
> Invalid markup declaration '
>
> Invalid token "" at root level of document.

and many more in every line of this file.

This errors have occured when system was starting up. 
I am using Asp .NET Core MVC 3.0.0.
Before this everything was working fine, any suggestions?

Comment: There's no `cvproj` extension. It should be `csproj`. This isn't a valid XML document either, the  elements never close

Comment: Which means, either the extension is wrong but you only posted part of the file, you spelled the extension wrong and posted only part of the file, or both extension and contents are wrong.

Comment: Can you show the actual and exact error message? Also, is that the full file, or did you leave something out? Because right now, there is at least a missing closing `</Project>` at the end.

Comment: @poke I posted part of a file. Right now, there is the full file with .csproj extention of course.

Comment: That's valid XML. You should describe what you did with more detail than "I have done migrations".

Comment: @GertArnold I just added more details.

Answer (score 1):

I try to create blank .net core 3.0 project and this csproj file is working fine

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Try to check your project extension file should be `.csproj`

Comment: It does not change anything, even after upgrade to 3.1.0, I have the same errors after run my application.